# HTML, PHP: Variables doesn't show up after form submit

Tags: php, html

After submitting the following form, the part `placeid=2` doesn't show up in the URL. Please assist.

```html
<form method="GET" action="localhost/place.php?placeid=2">
    <button class="yesbtn" type="submit">Yes</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to learn **[HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)**

Comment: Can you post your hole page. The problem is $id is not found in the current page.

Comment: and where does the $id come from?

Comment: The $id does not affect. Even if I change it to placeid=2. It still doesn't show up.

Comment: place.php? code as well

Comment: Yes show us code.php. It looks like there is the issue is in there.

Comment: My place.php is just displaying the value of placeid. <?php echo $_GET['placeid']; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested all here but if you want your script to work. You must use method="post". otherwise it won't work.

I tested

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="page.php?placeid=2">
            <button class="yesbtn" type="submit">Yes</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Worked http://paules.eu/form.php

The answer from Ayoub Elyalaoui will works to but you wanted coded in the action.

Answer (score 2):

This is really how you should be doing it. Using method="get" in your form will show the query parameters in the URL string, as in your original form.

**form.html:**

```
<form action="localhost/place.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="2" id="placeid" name="placeid">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

For submitting a parameter this way you can also use a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $id ?>">
```

Comment: What if I want to pass the value through URL?

Comment: If you have no method parameter in your form it will be in your form, but not if you have method="post" in your form.